# UITableView cells cannot be selected

Tags: uitableview

When I select a row on my `UITableView`, the call to the handler is never made...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I create the custom cells programmatically. User interaction is enabled on my `UITableView` and the data source and delegate are set to the File's Owner for the view controller the tale resides in. I am able to insert data, but touches are not detected. The cells do not even turn blue.

What am I missing?

I tried setting the table to allow selection:

```
   tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
```

EDIT:

More details - I have a `NSLog` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and it never gets printed. The cell does not even turn blue or look selected.

I changed the cells from my custom ones to regular `UITableViewCells` and I still can't select cells.

Comment: Also, make sure there are no gesture recognizers cancelling touches in your `UITableView`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has been posted long time ago but here is my answer for whom still stuck with this one:

```
   tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

Comment: Or of course setting the appropriate Editing flag for your UITableView in Interface Builder.